# Problema con la jerarquía de Wordpress y taxonomías personalizadas

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo un problema con la jerarquía de wordpress y las taxonomías.

Al principio me manejaba bien con las categorías propias del WP Core, eventualmente fui agregando `custom post types` para varias secciones que creé. El problema acá era el desorden que generaban las categorías del wp core, ya que todas las categorías que había agregado aparecían en TODOS mis custom posts, generando un pequeño desastre incómodo a la hora de categorizar las publicaciones de esos `custom posts  types`.

En ese entonces mi página funcionaba así:

```
index (inicio) --> page (criaturas) --> subpage (tipos de criaturas) --> single (criatura única)
```

Y todo estaba bien salvo el desorden de las categorías mencionadas anteriormente.

Revisando un poco encontré algo sobre las taxonomías personalizadas y decidí crear una para un tipo de post en particular, este `post type` se llama `Criaturas`. Hice el cambio de categorías del `wp core` a `taxonomía personalizadas` y comenzó el problema. Al parecer no estoy respetando la jerarquía ya que ahora se muestra de esta forma:

`inicio --> page (criaturas) --> Acá en vez de cargar la subpage (tipos de criaturas) me carga index.php`, con lo cual me hace creer que hay un problema jerarquico.

Creo que una imagen pueden decir bastante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto esperaba que cargara la `subpage (tipos de criaturas)` pero no es así, me manda directo al `index`, dandome a entender que me falta crear algún archivo donde pueda ver todos los tipos de criaturas y luego enviarme a un `single.php` cuando abra esa única criatura.

**¿Que necesito?**

- Necesito que sea como antes (ver imagen) pero usando las taxonomías
  personalizadas.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? ("Necesito que sea como antes (ver imagen) pero usando las taxonomías personalizadas." no es una pregunta, es un pedido de que alguien lo haga por vos...

Comment: [Habiendo entendido cómo funcionan y cómo WP organiza las taxonomías](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy). ¿Cuál es el problema o error? ¿Qué has revisado y con qué resultados? Eso de crear páginas `single.php` y demás no es del estilo de Wordpress, que existe para automatizar las cosas mediante child themes si fuera preciso y desde `functions.php`.

Comment: Lo solucioné. Debia colocar un archive.php